# Error on angular state

Tags: angularjs

This is the code I have:

```
angular.module("App").config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $injector) {
    $stateProvider
    .state("member", {
        url: "/member",
        views: {
            "" : {
                templateUrl: "/js/angular/partials/member/index.html",
                controller: 'MemberController'
            }
        }
    });
}).controller(
    "MemberController",
    ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$ocLazyLoad", "$location"],
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $ocLazyLoad, $location) {
        log("Members controller initialized.");
    }
);
```

I don't like to define the controller directly in the view, because that will make me create a lot of different functions, so I want define the controller once. However it says:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MemberController' is not a function, got string
```

I've tried change the controller to the very top, in another `angular.module("App").controller` definition but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing the location of the closing square bracket ]

```
.controller(
    "MemberController",
    ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$ocLazyLoad", "$location",
    function ($rootScope, $scope, $ocLazyLoad, $location) {
        log("Members controller initialized.");
    }
]);
```

Comment: Ok... that is weird. Why it was the solution? What is the difference? :S Thanks for this man!

Comment: The difference is the ] after '$location' :)